# Creating a stack that cannot have repeated values

Tags: python, stack

I'm just getting into python but am having issues with the concept of stacks! I have an assignment that is requiring me to create an unique stack where there cannot be two of the same values, however I am confused on how to run through the stack to check this.

```py
from stack import Stack

 class UniqueStack(Stack):

    """ UniqueStack has the same methods and functionality as Stack, but will only store one copy of a particular item at a time. If push is called with an item that is already in the UniqueStack, a ValueError should be raised with an appropriate error message. If push is called where item equals None, a TypeError should be raised like in the base class. Define and implement the relevant methods from the base Stack class to enable the behavior described above. New versions of __init__(), push(), and pop() should be sufficient. Hint: One option to implement this is to maintain an internal set() alongside the internal list. """
```

I have many more variations to do with stacks but if anyone has any thoughts/tips on how to start this base one I'll take them!

Comment: Can you share the code of Stack?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that uses a `set` to keep track of which elements are already in the stack. Main points:

1) When adding an element, check the set. And add to the stack and set both.

2) When removing an element, make sure you remove from the set as well.

```
class UniqueStack(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._seen = set()
        self._stack = list()

    def push(self, val):
        if val in self._seen:
            raise ValueError('Already in stack')
        self._stack.append(val)
        self._seen.add(val)

    def pop(self):
        if not self._stack:
            raise ValueError('stack is empty')
        retval = self._stack.pop(-1)
        self._seen.remove(retval)
        return retval

    def __str__(self):
        return '/'.join(map(str, self._stack))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stack = UniqueStack()
    for i in range(5):
        stack.push(i)
    print(stack)
    try:
        stack.push(4) # Error
    except:
        print("Got error")
        pass
    print(stack.pop())
    stack.push(4)
    print(stack)
```

Output:

```
0/1/2/3/4
Got error
4
0/1/2/3/4
```

Comment: He has a Stack object already so propbably he need to override only the push function, and also using ```exepet:``` without specifice exception is a bad practice

Comment: 1. OP did not add any explicit stack class in their question. 2. I know. it's just a sample code.

Comment: Is this similar to the concept of "overriding methods" in java?

Comment: @IsabelleCongdon My answer does not override any methods but you are free to do so. The approach i've used can be done with by overriding an existing stack class as well.